# Estimation of learning model with finite horizon forward-looking individuals

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, behavioral-economics, dynamic-programming, structural-estimation

I am stuck with the estimation of learning model where individuals are forward-looking in a finite horizon.

Specially, a user is watching a TV program containing many episodes, and he doesn't know the true 'quality' of the TV program, suppose he is a bayesian learner (he also knows that), so his perception of the quality of the TV program watching is updated by Bayes theorem, that is,
\begin{equation}
    Q(0) \sim \mathcal{N} (Q_0, \sigma_0^2)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    Q^E \sim \mathcal{N} (Q, \sigma_s^2)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    Q(t) = \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma_{t-1}^2}}{\frac{1}{\sigma_t^2}}Q(t-1) + \frac{\frac{1}{\sigma_s^2}}{\frac{1}{\sigma_t^2}}Q^E(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \sigma_t^2 = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sigma_{t-1}^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_s^2}}
\end{equation}
where $Q(0)$ is his prior belief of the quality of the TV program, $Q^E$ is the distribution of the true quality of the TV program, each time the user finished one episode, he received a experienced quality value sampled from $Q^E$, then his quality belief about the TV program  is updated by Bayes rule. $Q_t$ denotes the mean of his quality belief and $\sigma_t^2$ denotes the variance of his quality variance after watching episode $t$.

After finishing each episode, he will decide to stop watching forever ($d = 1$) or continuing ($d = 1$) according to his current utility and expected future utility, that is
\begin{align}
        u(Q(t), t, d, \epsilon_{t}(d); \Theta) & = \alpha Q(t) - \beta p + \epsilon_t(0) + \gamma \int\text{Emax}(Q(t+1), t+1) f(Q(t+1)|Q(t)) \text{d} Q(t+1), \text{if }d = 0  \\
& = \alpha Q(t) - \beta p + \epsilon_t(1), \text{if }d = 1\\                                        
\end{align}

where $p$ is the price per episode, $\gamma$ is the discount factor, and,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \text{Emax}(Q(t + 1), t + 1)  & =  \mathbb{E}\left[\max_{d \in \{0, 1\}} u(Q(t+1), t+1, d, \epsilon_{t+1}(d); \Theta)\right] \\
        & = \iint \max_{d\in \{0, 1\}} u(Q(t+1), t+1, d, \epsilon_{t+1}(d); \Theta) \text{d} G(\epsilon_{t+1}(0)) \text{d} G(\epsilon_{t+1}(1))
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
if we assume $\epsilon_t(d)$ is i.i.d. distributed Gumbel distribution, then we have,
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \text{Emax}(Q(t+1), t+1) & = \log\Big(\exp(\alpha Q(t+1) - \beta p) + \exp \big( u(\alpha Q(t+1) - \beta p) +          \\ & \qquad \gamma \int \text{Emax}(Q(t+1), t+1) f(Q(t+2) | Q(t+1)) \text{d} Q(t+1)\big)\Big) \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Suppose the TV program has $T$ episodes, then we can get the terminated condition:
\begin{equation}
    \text{Emax}(Q(T), T) = \log(2\exp(u(\alpha Q(T) - \beta p)))
\end{equation}

Suppose we have many users sequential watching data, we know when they stop reading. It seems like a simulated maximium likelihood method can estimate this model as we dont know the quality signal he received at each episode $t$. We can sample many times from $Q^E \sim \mathcal{N} (Q, \sigma_s^2)$ and result in a sequence of $Q(t)$ for each user, and by which we can implement Monte Carlo integration.

However, the question is, how can I calculate $\text{Emax}$, it relates to a high-dimentional integration. Is there any references to do it?

btw, the modelling framework is largely from

> Erdem, T., & Keane, M. P. (1996). Decision-Making Under Uncertainty: Capturing Dynamic Brand Choice Processes in Turbulent Consumer Goods Markets. Marketing Science, 15(1), 1–20. https://doi.org/10.1287/mksc.15.1.1